# SoapUi - Get Requests from multiple websides

Tags: soapui

I'm an absolutely newby in soapui so i have no idea how to create the following situation.
What i try to do is the following:
I have some Websites (more than 100) and i what to make an get request for each Webside. From each Webside i want to write the result (textbased result) into one file (one file for all requests). The request time for each Website is approximately 1 to 10 seconds (if this is relevant for the situation). The Links of the Websides are stored in an normal .txt file.
I know how to make one request via SoapUi, but it is not possible to handle this with a lot of Websides.

Comment: SoapUI is for consuming SOAP or REST web services. It sounds like you want to make a GET HTTP request ? Does each of those web sites expose web services ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the website is always the same. This means that only one web service is used. Each link returns different data values which are returned in a json format.
E.g.:

```
www.google.com/maps/1

www.google.com/maps/2

www.google.com/maps/3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a Functional (aka Data Driven Test) in SoapUI.  This functionality does exactly what you're asking.  E.g. for each item in file, call something and capture some data.

This functionality is locked down in the free version.  So I suppose that is the first question, do you have a licence?  If not, then search on Stack Overflow for solutions where people have created their own custom way of doing this in SoapUI.

Whilst you can use SoapUI to call websites, @ou_ryperd makes a good point.  Is SoapUI really the right tool for this?

You can build your own web-scraper using any programming language.  E.g. C#, Java, Node.js(Javascript), Python etc. etc.  There are plenty of on-line solutions/tutorials which you should be able to copy then modify.